# How to get a list out of a list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a disciplineList (each user has one) that contains the disciplines of an authorized teacher. I want to bring the discipline to each discipline of its students. I manage to bring out disciplines, but not students. I use spring boot and thymeleaf

I tried this code in my html:

```html
<ul type="none">
  <li th:each="discipline : ${disciplineList.disciplines}">
  <a href="" th:text="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-name"></a>
    <ul th:name="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-info" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(discipline.students)}">
      <p th:each="student : ${disciplines.students}"></p>
      <li th:text="${student.student}"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I get an error: Property or field 'students' cannot be found on null

if i try

```html
<div th:each="discipline : ${disciplineList.disciplines}">
   <span th:text="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-name"></span>
</div>
```

I get all of disciplines.

DisciplineListDto:

```java
String name;
List<DisciplineDto> disciplines;
```

DisciplineDto:

```java
long id;
@NotEmpty
String name;
List<StudentDto> students;
```

StudentDto:

```java
int Id;
String student;
```

I want to get this text:

Math
-Peter
-John
-Lisa

Physics
-Lisa
-Ashley

Comment: Typo: Should be `${discipline.students}` instead of `${disciplines.students}`.

Comment: @holmis83 this not worked too

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was what I wrote in the tag p

```html
th:each="student : ${disciplines.students}"
```

and closed it :)

I just had to write everything in li:

```html
<ul type="none">
  <li th:each="discipline : ${disciplineList.disciplines}">
  <a href="" th:text="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-name"></a>
   <ul th:name="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-info" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(discipline.students)}">
     <li th:each="student : ${discipline.students}" th:text="${student.student}"></li>      
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And thanks to @holmis83, you were right.